# QTextDocument default style sheet

Tags: css, qt, stylesheet

I try to draw a text on a QImage using  the QTextDocument.
How to set a default ("body") style?

Currently I use a `<p>` tag, like this

```
QPainter painter(_image);
QTextDocument doc;
doc.setDefaultStyleSheet("p { color : green; background-color : black; }");
doc.setHtml("<p>test 123</p>");
doc.drawContents(&painter,_image->rect());
```

I would like to get rid of `<p>` tag

```
doc.setHtml("test 123");
```

I have tried

```
doc.setDefaultStyleSheet("body { color : green; background-color : black; }");
doc.setDefaultStyleSheet("{ color : green; background-color : black; }");
doc.setDefaultStyleSheet("color : green; background-color : black; ");
doc.setDefaultStyleSheet("QImage { color : green; background-color : black; }");
```

*EDIT:*

I have also tried

```
doc.setDefaultStyleSheet("* { color : green; background-color : black; }");
```

Answer (score 8):

You should wrap content with `<body>` tag:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QTextDocument doc;
    doc.setDefaultStyleSheet("body { color : green; background-color : black; }");
    doc.setHtml("<body>test 123</body>");

    QTextEdit textEdit;
    textEdit.setDocument(&doc);
    textEdit.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, I felt like I tried everything before finding this answer. It works. Should be accepted. Once this is working it isn't hard to add the pen color using `painter.pen().color().name()` and `alphaF()` to fill in the `color` and `opacity` css options.